# PHP error namespace with SessionHandlerInterface

Tags: php, class

I have a problem with this PHP code that I'd like to solve.:

```
<?php    
namespace MyNamespace;

class MySessionHandler implements SessionHandlerInterface
{
    public function open($a, $b)
    {
    }
    public function close()
    {
    }
    public function read($sid)
    {
    }        
    public function write($sid, $data)
    {
    }        
    public function destroy($sid)
    {
    }
    public function gc($expire)
    {
    }
}

// ####################### error! ######################
$a = new MySessionHandler();
?>
```

When I run the code It outputs this error:
`Fatal error: Interface 'MyNamespace\SessionHandlerInterface' not found in /var/www/html/2.php on line 5`

(I have `PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4`)
I don't know what is its problem.

Comment: If `SessionHandlerInterface` is in the global space, then you have to prefix it with a backslash, `\SessionHandlerInterface`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have namespaced the code, and thus php is looking for the `SessionHandlerInterface` in the scope of your custom namespace. Basically, you'll have to tell php to look for the interface in the global/root space:

```
namespace MyNamespace;

class MySessionHandler extends \SessionHandlerInterface {
    // your implementation
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This interface like class doesn't show up because you have a **namespace** defined.

That's why you're getting the error:

`Fatal error: Interface 'MyNamespace\SessionHandlerInterface' not found`

You have two possibilities.

### Method 1. `use` the required namespace

---

under your namespace, you can just write the line:

```
use SessionHandlerInterface;
```

and all will be fine.

You can now implement this interface as usual.

```
<?php    
namespace MyNamespace;

use SessionHandlerInterface;

class MySessionHandler implements SessionHandlerInterface
{
    public function open($a, $b)
    {
    }
    public function close()
    {
    }
    public function read($sid)
    {
    }        
    public function write($sid, $data)
    {
    }        
    public function destroy($sid)
    {
    }
    public function gc($expire)
    {
    }
}

$a = new MySessionHandler();
?>
```

### Method 2.`implement` or `extend` "\SessionHandlerInterface"

---

You can `implement` or `extend` **SessionHandlerInterface**, putting a backslash after the **implements** or **extends** keyword, like this:

`\SessionHandlerInterface`

otherwise, the PHP parser will search for the class `SessionHandlerInterface` inside your namespace, and if you are not **using** the `SessionHandlerInterface` namespace (as in **Method 1**), the **Fatal Error** will occur.

```
<?php    
namespace MyNamespace;

class MySessionHandler implements \SessionHandlerInterface
{
    public function open($a, $b)
    {
    }
    public function close()
    {
    }
    public function read($sid)
    {
    }        
    public function write($sid, $data)
    {
    }        
    public function destroy($sid)
    {
    }
    public function gc($expire)
    {
    }
}

$a = new MySessionHandler();
?>
```